# Overloading function with different return type

Tags: c#, overloading

I have two functions with the same name and the main difference is just different return type. How could I overload the function in order to use the same name because sometimes I need point3d or point3f arrays, and the following function names gives error for being the same:

```
public static Point3d[] GetNGonCenters(this Mesh mesh)
{
    Point3d[] centers = new Point3d[mesh.Ngons.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.Ngons.Count; i++)
        centers[i] = mesh.Ngons.GetNgonCenter(i);

    return centers;
}

public static Point3f[] GetNGonCenters(this Mesh mesh)
{
    Point3f[] centers = new Point3f[mesh.Ngons.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.Ngons.Count; i++)
        centers[i] = (Point3f)mesh.Ngons.GetNgonCenter(i);

    return centers;
}
```

Comment: You can only overload on method arguments, not on return types.

Comment: You cannot overload a function on return type

Comment: The other option is creating a different static class for the extension method to sit in. The overloading wouldn't be an issue if they are in separate classes

Comment: Perhaps you can genericise your `Mesh` class and use `T[]` as your return type?

Comment: To see why this isn't possible, what would you expect to occur if you used `var bob = mesh.GetNGonCenters()`. How would it decide which method to call and what the type of `bob` is? It can't, so it won't let you do it.

Comment: It would be interesting to know your call sites/expected usage, it may shape the answers you get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler has no way of knowing what you're calling. I suggest making the names more descriptive like so:

```
public static Point3d[] GetNGonCenters3D(this Mesh mesh)
```

And

```
public static Point3f[] GetNGonCenters3F(this Mesh mesh)
```

---

Overloading will not work here as they're both using the same parameters, the compiler can't guess what return type you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use generics:

```
public static T[] GetNGonCenters<T>(this Mesh mesh) where T : Point3d
{
    T[] centers = new T[mesh.Ngons.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < mesh.Ngons.Count; i++)
        centers[i] = (T)mesh.Ngons.GetNgonCenter(i);

    return centers;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to do this when one of the possible return types is `byte[]`? It gives error "Invalid constraint type. A type used as a constraint must be an interface, a non-sealed class or a type parameter."

Comment: Actually, even if my problem with `byte[]` didn't exist, this answer isn't very useful because you apparently have to always specify the generic type argument explicitly. I.e., the OP would have to call either `GetNGonCenters<Point3D>()` or `GetNGonCenters<Point3F>()`, in which case it makes more sense to have two methods with different names.

Comment: @renniepet having two methods goes against the DRY principle. (Don't repeat yourself)... using dotnet generics makes your solution more DRY ... Even if you have to be explicit when you call the methods with different generic arguments

Comment: how can you convert from centers to bytes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overload a function you have to have a function with the same name, as you do have, but different parameters. You are not overloading your functions because they have the same name and the same parameter. You either have to rename the function or add a new parameter to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload two functions with the only difference being a return type. C# uses the parameter list as the context.

Two ideas:

1. You could have the function return an object and typecast it in the call.
2. You could include a dummy variable in the header to differentiate the method context.

Here is a good link to a paper on C# overloading.
[Overloading in depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overload a method by only having different return types. A method is found when you call it by name and provide it with the parameters, not by what object you're expecting to be returned.

Consider what would happen in the following example (note that it will not compile):

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Number { get; set; }

    private void DoSomething(int num)
    {
        Number += num;
    }

    private int DoSomething(int num)
    {
        // Bad example, but still valid.
        Number = num + 2;
        return num * num;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();

// Which version of the method do I want to call here?
// Most likely it is the one that returns void,
// but you can ignore the return type of any method call.
foo.DoSomething(3);
```